# Invisible layer in Illustrator CC

Tags: adobe-illustrator, layers

I'm very new to Illustrator CC. I did something to make layer 2 invisible and I don't know how to undo it.

A picture is worth a thousand words..

[image]

Answer (score 5):

Not entirely sure how you would do so accidentally (there's no default keyboard shortcut as far as I know), but you've set the group's (not the layer itself) opacity to 0.

Simple fix... set the opacity back to "100".

[image]

Tip: You can see in the layers panel if a layer has any appearance attributes other than a basic fill/stroke (such as a modified opacity) by the filled dot alongside that layer.

Comment: We just answered 45 seconds apart :)) But since your answer came 45 seconds early, while I was uploading my image, I'll delete mine cause there's no need for two answers saying the same thing :D

Comment: @Alin I'll try and upload my images slower next time :)

Comment: Not too slow though, we don't want others to notice :)) Just 46 seconds or so :D Cheers !

Comment: ok maybe it wasn't an accident but I'm doing all these things for the first time and have No short term memory anymore,lol,  so i can't remember what i did 3 sec ago.   Thank you for responding.